# Error : out of domain error mathprog

Tags: mathprog

I'm a new user of GNU GLPK and I 'm facing an error of this type.
can you please help to resolve?
Error msg:

```
Generating EQ_SpecifiedDemand...
OSeMOSYS_test1-22.txt:193: SpecifiedAnnualDemand[TUNISIA,ELEC,2010] out of domain MathProg model processing error
```

Here are my params:

```
param SpecifiedAnnualDemand{y in YEAR,f in FUEL,r in REGION};

param SpecifiedDemandProfile{y in YEAR, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, r in REGION};

param YearSplit{y in YEAR,l in TIMESLICE};

s.t. EQ_SpecifiedDemand{r in REGION, l in TIMESLICE, f in FUEL, y in YEAR}: 

SpecifiedAnnualDemand[r,f,y]*SpecifiedDemandProfile[r,f,l,y] / 

YearSplit[l,y]=RateOfDemand[r,l,f,y];
```

any clue?

Comment: I think it's a model issue